# Google App-engine: How to restrict host header injection for google owned domains

Tags: go, google-app-engine

I've developed an REST service using Golang Chi framework and deployed the same in GCP app engine standard environment. I've used `secure:always` in **app.yaml** so API always serves in HTTPS.

When we are calling API using command `curl -X GET "HTTP_<API_ENDPOINT>" -H "Host: blogger.com"` - I saw API response is 301 (Redirecting) and location header of response contains "blogger.com"
["blogger.com" is a google owned domain]

But,
When we are calling API using command `curl -X GET "HTTP_<API_ENDPOINT>" -H "Host: msn.com"`  - I saw API response is 404.
["msn.com" is a non google owned domain]

I want to block any host header injection. I tried to fix it in application level but it seems app engine itself doing this redirection before request reached to application layer.

Kindly advise

Comment: you want to know the actual host header that client sent so that you can reject the request?

Comment: Can you share the app.yaml file ?

Comment: Yes,  to reject the request or marked the request as BAD request

Comment: Sample app.yaml is:                                                                                          
<pre>```runtime: go114
instance_class: F1
handlers:
- url: /v1/.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301 ```</pre>

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to restrict this behavior. The engineering team reviewed it in the past and considered negligible and not subject to exploits. The only thing you can do is to restrict such injection on client-side applications level.